# Windows XP setup refuses to format HDD. What now?

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, formatting

I found a very very old laptop in my garage (Acer Travelmate 613TXV) and I'm curious about how well it will work. My skills are above average but when I try to install Windows XP on it (on a 4 GB HDD from a friend) the laptop says that the HDD has 14000 MB and I can't format it.

I put the HDDon my laptop, formatted it, then made a partition. When I insert it in the old laptop it tells me that it has 14000 MB unallocated space and cannot be formatted.

Is there a hardware problem on that laptop? I installed Windows XP on older laptop than this and didn't have any problems.

In BIOS, the HDD is visible, but doesn't show the capacity of it.

Comment: i can accept giveing me negative reputation when the answere is verry easy and you know it... if you don`t know the answere.. leave it.. and watch you`re business

Comment: Can you give us a make and model of the HDD you are trying to install? Can you boot to the recovery console and run a CHKDSK on the HDD to make sure its good?

Answer (score 1):

Download and burn the bootable ISO for [Gnome Partition Editor](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) to a CD.  Boot off that CD and use it to erase the hard drive and create a new partition.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to discern if the problem is with the HDD itself (corrupt disc/ board) or with the Windows XP's ACHI driver for the system. I recommend trying another HDD in the laptop, if it works, you know the HDD is a no-go, otherwise I would recommend getting specific drivers for the laptop (if possible).